# Beginner in java game development

Tags: java, opengl

I want to get into game development with Java, and would like to export the game to mobile devices in the future (both android and IOs). I have some background in Java, and wants to make simple game with it first for practice.

Game tutorials that I have came across with java tutorial uses JFrame, JPanel, and canvas to draw the game. I, also, ran across tutorial started off using teaching GraphicsDevice api in java.awt library. I am confused. From the description of the GraphicsDevice api, I think it allows the game to be full screen; however, isn't that achievable with JFrame already? Can anyone tell me whats the difference with and without GraphicsDevice api?

Also, I came across some posts suggesting OpenGL EU. If I understand correctly, it allows game graphics performance to be boosted. Is it encouraged to use OpenGL for every game? Is it something similar to GraphicsDevice api? If yes, I would assume it can not co-exist in the same game with GraphicsDevices api; otherwise, I would assume they can co-exist and the game can take advantage of both api. Correct me if I am wrong...I am really not understanding much so far.

Comment: You need to investigate active and passive rendering techniques to understand the use of `Canvas` and `BufferStrategy`.  Full Screen Exclusive mode provides more power to you, as the OS doesn't need to keep interrupting you to make updates it needs and other cool stuff. Also, research double buffering, it will make `BufferStrategy` make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Game tutorials that I have came across with java tutorial uses JFrame,
>   JPanel, and canvas to draw the game. I, also, ran across tutorial
>   started off using teaching GraphicsDevice api in java.awt library. I
>   am confused. From the description of the GraphicsDevice api, I think
>   it allows the game to be full screen; however, isn't that achievable
>   with JFrame already? Can anyone tell me whats the difference with and
>   without GraphicsDevice api?

`Canvas` provides access to `BufferStrategy` which provides you with the ability to take control over the rendering process.  This is commonly known as active rendering, as opposed to the way Swing works, which uses a passive rendering process

[Full-Screen Exclusive Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/) provides some benifits over frame based rendering, typically, it will be faster as you have exclusive access to the screen without hinderance from other windows or the OS wanting to perform extra painting due to changes it (the OS) may detect/require

> Also, I came across some posts suggesting OpenGL EU. If I understand
>   correctly, it allows game graphics performance to be boosted. Is it
>   encouraged to use OpenGL for every game? Is it something similar to
>   GraphicsDevice api? If yes, I would assume it can not co-exist in the
>   same game with GraphicsDevices api; otherwise, I would assume they can
>   co-exist and the game can take advantage of both api. Correct me if I
>   am wrong...I am really not understanding much so far.

Java, at least through Swing, not sure about AWT, can use both OpenGL and DirectX for it's rendering pipeline, having said that, there are some additional benefits to using OpenGL bindings directly, one would be the inclusion of 3D capabilities.

I'd recommend trying to develop concepts and algorithms first, understand how to keep the game state separate from the game view and game controller, understand the purpose of the main game loop, for example, these concepts will always be important regardless of what you are developing...

iOS has OpenGL bindings/capabilities, so learning them eventually will still be a good idea, but they could get in the way to start with.

The OpenGL bindings are just that, they are away to allow you to render through the OpenGL drivers and API through the use of AWT based components.  I also believe that some OpenGL bindings also attempt to objectify the API to make it more OO - personally, I like the idea, but some people won't like it.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your answer! I have some experience in MVC, but I am not really proficient with it. I do plan on getting more practice with it once I get into the designing process. I think I will start off with reading more about BufferStrategy as you suggested in the comments.